# Not all Sharepoint list items are returned and not all columns can be recognized

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I am using the following code to download a list from my company's Sharepoint to my program. The list name is "Resurser".

```
var context = new ClientContext(@"MY_SHAREPOINT_SERVER_URL");
var passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "MY_PASSWORD".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
SharePointOnlineCredentials _myCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("MY_USERNAME", passWord);
context.Credentials = _myCredentials;
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Resurser");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();  
query.ViewXml = "<View/>";  
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);  
context.Load(list);  
context.Load(items);  
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FieldValues["Title"]);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

What I can clearly see is that I only receive 77 items from the list whereas the list has much more.

How can I:

1. Download the entire list;
2. Read through list items as they appear on Sharepoint, because for each item, I am receiving a number of `FieldValues` that do not look a lot like the list I see on Sharepoint. In the code above `item.FieldValues["Title"]` returns the values for the first column of the list ("Namn"). But I don't seem to find all the columns I am looking for.

Here is a snapshot of the list on Sharepoint:
[image]

And here is a picture of one of the items when I output it as "key : value".
[image]

So is there a simpler way to iterate through a Sharepoint list and download all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you are not getting values for all available fields in list, right? In that case you could consider to *explicitly* specify what field values to retrieve using [`ClientRuntimeContext.Load<T> method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536388.aspx). The below example demonstrates how to retrieve values for all list fields:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Contacts");
ctx.Load(list, l => l.Fields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
//get all available fields in list
var fieldNames = list.Fields
                 .Where(f => f.FieldTypeKind != FieldType.Computed && f.FieldTypeKind != FieldType.File && f.FieldTypeKind != FieldType.Recurrence && f.FieldTypeKind != FieldType.CrossProjectLink && f.FieldTypeKind != FieldType.AllDayEvent)
                 .Select(f => f.InternalName).ToList();
 //construct expression to retrieve all field values   
 var includes = fieldNames.Select(name => (Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>) (icol => icol.Include(i => i[name])));

 var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
 ctx.Load(items, includes.ToArray());
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```